# Caller ID on Android - How to Suppress/Delay Default incoming call screen?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

We are developing Caller ID application and till now we are able to replace default incoming call screen with our own layout/caller ID screen following http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html with CALL_STATE_RINGING

However, the issue we are facing is as follows:
a) When phone gets incoming call, the default incoming call screen gets priority and gets displayed immediately
b) after 1-2 seconds, our caller ID screen come up.
we want to avoid/suppress/delay default incoming call screen completely so that user experience will be better.

Comment: How did you do this ? I used your code below but I still can see the default caller screen then mine appears after that.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't found out a way to totally suppress the default screen. However a smaller delay (500 ms) before the startActivity works good for me.
Also, I have the following flags into my Intent to start my custom activity. My code looks something like :

```
if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state))
        {
            SystemClock.sleep(500 * 1);
            Log.d("MPR", "Its Ringing [" + number + "]");
            Intent startMain = new Intent();
            startMain.setClassName("com.foo.TIC", "com.foo.TIC.TestInComing");
            startMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
            startMain.putExtra("PNO", number);
            context.startActivity(startMain);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If we use the Broadcast Recieiver then it is possible to use our own dialogbox and the screen.